# SPFile.MoveTo in App?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app

What would be the easiest way in a SharePoint hosted app to move a list item to a different folder inside the same list? Something similar to server-side SPFile.MoveTo (which preserves ID -> workflows keep on working)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the javascript api to do it. You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245487.aspx

Comment: Hi SimTex, Please add the relevant code from the link to your answer. Just in case if the link stops working.